# Shinobi Charts bar graph Customising

Tags: ios, graph, charts

I'm using Shinobi Controls Charts to do this project and i'm having some trouble to find ou how to customise my chart to look as close as possible to this:

[image: Target graph]

Here is what i have so far:

[image: So far i have this]

The labels at the bottom are the ones that are represented as [name] in the first chart.

The colores of the bars are ok i know how to change them. My problem resides on the labels on the top of each bar and the grid and background grid.

1) How can i remove the grid and change the graph color to transparant? `chart.xAxis.style.gridStripeStyle.showGridStripes = NO;` does not remove the grid.

2) The radial series had a callback where i could change the labels position, but after taking a look at all the documentation that comes with the demo i can't find anything to change the position of the axis's labels for a bar graph and add more complexity like an image and 2 or 3 labels to it. Also those boxes have to move along with bars.

Does anyone know how to do this 2 topics?

Thank you in advance for any given help.

**EDIT :**
I've been able to remove the axis with

```
axis.style.gridStripeStyle.showGridStripes = NO; // removes the main bar
axis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = NO; // removes the grid bars
```

Comment: for #2: do you mean - (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis ?

Comment: nice that seams just like what i need how did i miss that. I was looking for something similar to `sChart:alterLabel:forDatapoint:atSliceIndex:inRadialSeries:` and didn't notice that one. Gona give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Added it as answer for others to come along.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with ShinobiCharts as well, I'm trying to change what appears in my XAxis, how did u manage to insert [investment1] and [investment2] into your XAxis? Instead of just numbers?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer about making the chart background transparent?  (That's what led me here.)  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie try one of this lines or all (i use all because i want everything transparent) `chart.plotAreaBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` `chart.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` `chart.canvasAreaBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thx.  plotAreaBacgroundColor was what I wanted.

Comment: @Hugo Alves how did you achieved to have custom background texture for Shinobi chart?

Comment: @ChethanShetty I think i was able to do it. I haven't worked with shinobi charts for a long while now, but i think jimpic's solution helped

Comment: @HugoAlves thanks for the reply :)
I found the solution to have background to clear color, I used `[_shinobiChart setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`
`_shinobiChart.plotAreaBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
which works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second point, use

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark
beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first point use

```
chart.axis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = NO
```

Comment: ty for the answer, but this has been completed along time ago. Also after the edit tag I pointed out that I already have been able to remove the axis